# Input Date causa erro 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Toda vez que insiro um `input`  do tipo `date` no meu `form`, o servidor retorna erro 400. Já tentei de tudo, quando retiro o campo `date` não dá o erro.

Meu controller:

```
package br.com.starcode.agenda.controller;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import br.com.starcode.agenda.domain.Usuario;
import br.com.starcode.agenda.service.UsuarioService;

@Controller
public class UsuarioController {

    @Autowired
    UsuarioService UsuarioService; 

    @RequestMapping(value="/usuario", params="new")
    ModelAndView novoUsuario() {
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        usuario.setDataNascimento(new Date());
        return new ModelAndView("cadastrar-usuario")
                .addObject("usuario", usuario);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/usuario", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    ModelAndView confirmarNovo(
            Usuario novoUsuario,
            @RequestParam(value="dataNascimento", required=false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date dtNasc,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        try {
            novoUsuario.setDataNascimento(dtNasc);
            //insert 
            UsuarioService.insert(novoUsuario);
            //success
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "Registro '" + novoUsuario.getIdUsuario() + "' inserido com sucesso!");
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ModelAndView("cadastrar-usuario")
                    .addObject("erro", e.getMessage())
                    .addObject("usuario", novoUsuario);
        }
    }

}
```

E o JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Coleções - Cadastrar Usuário</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="<c:url value="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:url value="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

<style type="text/css">
  body {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background-image: url(img/album-covers.jpg);
  }

  .form-signin {
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 19px 29px 29px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  }

  .container {
    max-width: 650px;
    padding: 10px;
  }

</style>

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" style="background-color:#ffffff" >

            <h1>Cadastrar Usuário</h1>
            <p>Faça seu cadastro abaixo e monte já suas coleções!</p>

                    <form id="form-cadastrar-usuario" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="<c:url value="/usuario" />" >


                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">Nome:</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite seu nome" name="nomeUsuario" id="nomeUsuario" value="${usuario.nomeUsuario}" >
                        </div><p/>

                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">E-mail:</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail" name="emailUsuario" id="emailUsuario" value="${usuario.emailUsuario}" >
                        </div><p/>

                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">Sobrenome:</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite seu sobrenome" name="sobrenomeUsuario" id="sobrenomeUsuario" value="${usuario.sobrenomeUsuario}" >
                        </div><p/>

                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">Senha:</span>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite uma senha" name="senhaUsuario" id="senhaUsuario" value="${usuario.senhaUsuario}" >
                        </div><p/>

                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">Data de Nascimento:</span>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite a data do seu nascimento" name="dataNascimento" id="dataNascimento" value="<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${usuario.dataNascimento}" />" />
                        </div><p/>

                        <br>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" >Enviar</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" >Limpar</button>
                        <a href="<c:url value="/" />" class="btn btn-large btn-danger" >Cancelar</a>

                    </form>             

    </div>

        <!-- MENSAGENS -->
<div class="container-fluid">

  <c:if test="${not empty param.erro or not empty erro}">
  <div class="alert alert-danger fade in text-center" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Fechar</span></button>
    <strong>${param.erro}${erro}</strong>
  </div>
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="${not empty param.msg or not empty msg}">
  <div class="alert alert-success fade in text-center" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Fechar</span></button>
    <strong>${param.msg}${msg}</strong>
  </div>
  </c:if>

</div>


<jsp:include page="template-footer.jsp" />
```

Comment: Olá, caro aprendiz! Ia lhe dar boas vindas, mas vejo que já está no site há algum tempo. Espero que continue fazendo um bom proveito dele. Há uma comunidade de programação vibrante por aqui. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Origem do problema

Este tipo de erro é característico do Spring MVC e ocorre quando ele não consegue fazer fazer o *binding* de algum dado da requisição para algum parâmetro ou *model*.

Neste caso, é porque o Spring MVC não sabe qual o formato esperado para o campo `dataNascimento` da sua classe `Usuario`.

Mesmo tendo colocado a anotação `@DateTimeFormat` no seu parâmetro `dtNasc`, o Spring MVC ainda vai tentar preencher o atributo de `Usuario`.

## Solução simples, porém nãa recomendada

A solução mais simples no seu caso seria mudar o nome do campo no seu formulário para que o Spring não tente fazer o *binding* automático no atributo `dataNascimento`.

Porém, não recomendo isso porque seria pouco intuitivo e o Spring oferece mais de uma forma de resolver o problema sem gambiarras.

## Configurar um *property editor* no *controller*

Bem, você já deve saber que campos `input` do tipo `date` enviam os valores no formato `yyyy-mm-dd`, então para você deve informar isso ao Spring de alguma forma.

Uma delas é configurar um *property editor* na sua classe controladora.

Exemplo:

```
@InitBinder
void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}
```

Há um exemplo funcional disso num [projeto de exemplo que tenho no meu GitHub](https://github.com/utluiz/spring-examples/blob/master/agenda-web-completa/src/main/java/br/com/starcode/agenda/controller/EntradaController.java).

Note que o método acima afeta a interpretação de data para todas as requisições do *controller*.

## Configurar o atributo no *model*

O problema também seria resolvido ao anotar o atributo `dataNascimento` na sua classe de modelo com a anotação `@DateTimeFormat`.

Exemplo:

```
public class Usuario {

    ...

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dataNascimento;

    ...

}
```

Comment: problema resolvido tanto com a property editor quanto com a alteração no model, optei por usar o property editor. Muito obrigado!